# Convert money to text and keep format

Tags: sql, intersystems

I need to show a dollar range in a query but when I concatenate the values I lose the comma in the output.

```
select
'$'||CAST(ROUND(MIN(db.INITIAL_BALANCE),-1) AS money)
||' to '||
'$'||CAST(ROUND(MAX(db.INITIAL_BALANCE),-1) AS money) AS Balance_Range
```

the output is 
$2060 to $73690

desired output
$2,060 to $73,690

Any suggestions on this?

Intersystems Cache is my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'$'||TRIM(tochar(MIN(db.Account_Balance),'9,999,999'))|| ' to ' ||'$'||TRIM(tochar(max(db.Account_Balance),'9,999,999'))
```

gave me what I needed .. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think, that you even had commas ?
The [documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_cast) says nothing about formatting value.

> MONEY and SMALLMONEY are currency numeric data types. The scale for currency data types is always 4.

```
SELECT CAST('123123' AS money)
```

this query will return `123123.0000`, as expected

As I see, at least there are two ways how to do it.

- Define your own datatype, same as [%Currency](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?APP=1&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25Library.Currency) as an example, where you can change scale number, and format. But you should change to this type all properties, in all classes, where you need it.
- Or you can define new SQL Function, which will format all numbers as needed.

Something like below:

```
Class Sample.Utils Extends %RegisteredObject
{

ClassMethod ToMoney(pValue As %Integer = 0) As %String [ SqlProc, SqlName= "TO_MONEY"]
{
    quit "$ " _ $fnumber(pValue, ",", 2)
} 

}
```

And Query `SELECT Sample.TO_MONEY(1234567)`, will return `$ 1,234,567.00`